# Server Side Includes for apache Sling

Tags: apache, webserver, jetty, sling, ssi

I am working with apache `Sling`. I would like to activate the `Server Side Includes` (SSI) for pages generated from Sling. I have created one example in my localhost throw the apache configuration. It works properly. I should add some properties:

```
AddType text/html .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
Options +Includes
```

How can I apply the configuration `Sling`? What i know that the web Server for 'Sling' is 'Jetty' and the page could not be generated from two servers at the same time: I mean 'Jetty' for normal content und 'Http Server' for SSI. Can I use for example proxy redirection ? or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want SSI includes you should be able to proxy Sling via Apache using `mod_proxy` or something similar and then interpret the server-side include directives.

I'd encourage you to also look into [Sling Dynamic Includes](https://github.com/apache/sling/tree/trunk/contrib/extensions/sling-dynamic-include), which is a Sling module that makes working with SSI and ESI much easier.